# Recharts scatter plot with axis lines through 0

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am trying to create a scatter plot chart that looks like this:
[Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wu4n.png)

I have tried playing around with the XAxis and YAxis components but can't find any props or examples where the axis lines go through 0 rather than going at the left and bottom of the chart. I would have thought the standard design of a chart is to have the x axis at y=0 and the y axis at x=0, so I am surprised to find no support for this in Recharts. If this is not possible in Recharts, is there another React library that is more customizable that I might use instead?